# Textbox is filtering backspace key

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my javascript function below. Currently, the function restricts the letters that can be typed in it. The problem is: If the user presses <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, that event is being filtered out. How to I accept the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function verifABC(evt) {
        var keyCode = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        var accept = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        if (accept.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(keyCode)) >= 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
            
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
 <input type="date" name="dateEnf"  class="form-control" maxlength="30" onkeypress="return verifABC(event);"  id="datepicker" placeholder="">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Learn [ask] and [mcve]. It's only a 5 minute read and will save you hours. We want to help, but we need some context. Please don't place a space between "?" and the last word. Also, capitalize "i". We put a high value on proper spelling here.

Answer (score 0):

You should check first for `KeyboardEvent.key` before checking `.which` or `.keyCode`, as the last two are deprecated in favor of `.key`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

They're deprecated precisely because browsers can vary in the codes they return. The documentation for `.key` helpfully lists a number of key values, including the one for backspace, so that ought to answer your question and several others besides.